# Unable to resolve issue with string object not callable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[@id='btn2']")).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

This is giving me an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to resolve it, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). You need to provide a [mre], because if we can't reproduce your issue we can't help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The rigth way to do that is like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='btn2']").click()
```